# Admin bar appears empty in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Admin bar appears after adding code to the functions.php

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_true' );
```

but empty except for the WP logo and the search on the right.

I installed latest version of twentyTwelve, it didn't appear,after adding the same code to the theme's functions.php it appears with the same problem.

So I don't think it has to do with the theme.. So I deactivated all plugins, And I still have the same problem.

[image: Imgur]

Note: There is no problem with the admin bar in the Dashboard. Also I checked the HTML structure, it's not hidden by CSS.

`<?php wp_footer(); ?> + <?php wp_header(); ?>` are defined in the themes header and footer.

Comment: It works in the dashboard but not when viewing your site? What happens when you change themes?

Comment: Same thing, I changed the theme to TwentyTwelve same issue.

Comment: Odd, did you try a new theme (freshly downloaded)? If all plugins are removed and a fresh theme is doing it I'd replace everything with a fresh copy then drop in your old wp-config and see if it still does it.

Comment: Yes I tried a fresh installation of twentyTwelve theme.
I'll try what you suggested and get back here

Comment: Another thought... got an ad blocker running on your browser? Tried different browsers?

Comment: Ad blocker disabled, tried different browsers. Tried fresh wordpress installation, tried fresh fresh theme. tried both custom and twentytwelve with all plugins deactivated... nothing at all

Comment: If you do a totally fresh install and it is still missing then something else is wrong. Trippy though. Is it somewhere you can link it?

Comment: http://www.fevikmisjonskirke.no/    Now I hid the bar "removed the code from functions.php" I'll add it again

Comment: Still blank when you are logged in as admin? Also, is the core modified or is everything in themes/plugins like it should be?

Comment: Yes it's still blank, as you see in the attached image. There is nothing modified. Could it be an .htaccess thing? or a server thing, or something edited in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the toolbar is forced to load (via show_admin_bar) but a user is not logged in it has nothing to show the user. When this happens it looks exactly like your screen shot with just the WP and search icons present. The toolbar will load anytime a user is logged in though so there is no reason to force it to load unless you intend to modify its behavior to include actions for anonymous users.

I was able to recreate this easily in a clean install but only if there was no user logged in. If this is happening to you when a user is logged in then I suggest a fresh install of WP in a subdirectory, or locally, then enabling your theme and plugins one by one until it breaks so you know which component is causing the problem.

Comment: No, I am logged in as an admin with full privileges and it sill doesn't show anything.  I tried a fresh install and everything, but still..

Comment: Fresh install as in new database, totally wiped all files and replaced them and when you login as admin it is blank (before readding stuff or enabling plugins/themes)?

Comment: That is great news. Start adding stuff back and see what was causing it.